# Ember CLI - not transitioning to loading templates

Tags: javascript, templates, ember.js, loading, ember-cli

I have an Ember CLI project, and outside of the application level, I can't seem to get any loading templates to show.

Here's my router:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('users', function () {
    this.route('detail', { path: '/:user_id' });
  });
});
```

I have a template located at /app/templates/loading.hbs.

[According to the documentation on the Emberjs wesite](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/)
, this template should show for any of my routes that return a promise, but it doesn't.

I've also tried adding the following templates, to no avail:

- /app/templates/users/loading.hbs
- /app/templates/users/detail-loading.hbs

If I put a template at /app/templates/users-loading.hbs, the template does display during the intermediate transition to the users route, but that is not a good solution to use across my application.

That hacky solution aside, I still can't find a way to get the loading template to show at all for transitions to the users-detail route.

Any thoughts are much appreciated!

Comment: I recreated your routes in an Ember CLI app from scratch and I am able to see a loading screen for the details route if I put a template at `app/users/detail-loading.hbs`. What does your model hook for the details page look like?

Comment: Also, if you have the [Ember Inspector](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-inspector) browser addon (which you should!), open it up and take a look at the "/# Routes" listing. Does it show a loading route and template path for the details page?

Comment: The loading route is only active as long as the model isn't loaded

Comment: @TomNetzband - Thank you for trying that! I haven't actually defined a route for the details--I'm using the 'free' route I get from ember that automatically passes the ID to the route when I link to a specific user. The Ember inspector does indeed show a route named users.detail_loading.

Comment: You're not going to see a loading screen if you don't have a defined route loading a model.